# Different behavior of undefined reference error on linux gcc during linking with object file vs static library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, clang

I have following two source codes and want to link them.

```c
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

void lib2();

void lib1(){
    lib2();
    return 0;
}
```

```c
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I've used `gcc -c main.c` and `gcc -c test.c` to generate objects files

```
$ ls *.o
main.o  test.o
```

and I've used `ar rcs test.a test.o` command to generate static library(`test.a`) from object file `test.o`

Then, I tried to build executable by linking `main.o` with `test.a` or `test.o`. As far as I know, a static library file(.a extension) is a kind of simple collection of object files(.o). so I expected both would give same result: error or success. *but it didn't*.

Linking with the object file gives `undefined reference` error.

```
$ gcc -o main main.o test.o
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `lib1':
test.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `lib2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

but linking with the static library doesn't give any error and success on compilation.

```
$ gcc -o main main.o test.a
$
```

Why is this happening? and how can I get undefined reference errors even when linking with static libraries?

Comment: Try calling `lib1()` from `main()`  (it's still not guaranteed to give an error but is more likely to)

Comment: Yes, by calling/referencing `lib1()` from `main.c`, I can get undefined reference error for either object file or static library. but I want to get whole undefined reference errors even if these are't referenced actually.

Comment: objects and libraries are treated differently by the linker.

Comment: Solution: linking with `--whole-archive`. e.g. `ld --whole-archive -o main main.o test.a` or `gcc -o main -Wl,--whole-archive test.a main.o -Wl,--no-whole-archive`

Comment: https://litaotju.github.io/c++/2020/07/24/Whole-Archive-in-static-lib/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code contains a function call expression then the language standard requires a function definition exists. (See C11 6.9/3). If you don't provide a definition then it is undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required .

The rule was written this way so that implementation vendors aren't forced to perform analysis to determine if a function is ever called or not; for example in your library scenario the compiler isn't forced to dig around in the library if none of the rest of the code contains anything that references that library.

It's totally up to the implementation what to do, and in your case it decides to give an error in one case and not the other.  To avoid this, you can provide definitions for all the functions you call.

You might be able to modify the behaviour in the first case by using linker options such as elimination of unused code sections. Another thing you can do is call `lib1()` from `main()` -- this is still not guaranteed to produce an error but is more likely to.

Comment: The rationale is different. Imagine library where some functions require symbols from the object files (like callback functions). If linker would analyze any object in the library your program would have to have all those objects and functions defined even if you do not use them

Comment: @0___________ I don't see how that is different to what I said

Comment: Understood. It is up to implementation as you said and as @0___________ said 'objects and libraries are treated differently by the linker', it seems in my case linker decide to raise undefined reference error once a object file is given, but not a static library. For finding all undefined references, I should extract all object files from static library and link with them, or use other methods like `nm` command. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the "why .o is different from .a" part.

Comment: @EmployedRussian it's "because the implementation does things differently"

Answer (score 0):

Force the linker to do some work use `-flto` option and the error will go away.

`ld` does not search libraries for objects which are not used it only searches for symbols used in object files. Imagine that you have a library where some functions require defined callbacks. If you do not have them in every program you link against the library even if you do not use those functions.

Comment: I don't see how callbacks apply.  Callbacks are implemented via function pointers, which the linker in general can't know the run-time value of, but the function pointer itself will always exist.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected both would give same result: error or success. but it didn't.

Your expectation is incorrect. A good explanation of the difference between `.o` and `.a` with respect to linking is [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).